# Write a file to Roaming folder using NSIS script

Tags: c#, deployment, nsis

I am using NSIS to make exe for a desktop application in c# and i have to write few files to the AppData Roaming folder for the user

I tried the below code

```
 !define ROAMING_FOLDER_ROOT "$APPDATA\APPDUMMY\APPFILES"
 MessageBox MB_OK 'AppDATA FOLDER "${ROAMING_FOLDER_ROOT}"'  #here i am getting the correct path of the Appdata roaming folder frm variable
Section -Additional
SetOutPath "$ROAMING_FOLDER_ROOT"
SetOverwrite off 
File "C:\MYAPPSOURCECODE\BIN\BookStore.sqlite"
SetOverwrite ifnewer
File "C:\MYAPPSOURCECODE\BIN\AppSettings.xml"
File "C:\MYAPPSOURCECODE\BIN\Resources\defData.xml"
File "C:\MYAPPSOURCECODE\BIN\Resources\dummy.html"
SetOutPath "$ROAMING_FOLDER_ROOT\Resources"
File "C:\MYAPPSOURCECODE\BIN\Resources\appjsfile.js"
SectionEnd
```

While i am trying to do the same with $LocalAppData its writing to the AppDAta Local folder  but i want to make it writable to Roaming folder

Comment: What is your question exactly?
If you want to write into Roaming folder - use $APPDATA. If you want to write into Local folder - use accordingly $LOCALAPPDATA.
Your code looks right.

Comment: I am trying to write a file to ROAMING folder but this code is actually not writing to Roaming folder . I can see the files are generated inside C:\\\ProgramData FOlder which is the common area for all apps. Cant see any reason why its not writing to Appdata Roaming folder

Comment: The code you posted does not compile. After moving MessageBox to a section/function you will still get a compiler warning that you really should pay attention to!

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the code you posted you see that in the `MessageBox` call you referenced the `${ROAMING_FOLDER_ROOT}` define but when calling `SetOutPath` you are referencing a variable called `$ROAMING_FOLDER_ROOT` and this probably produces a compiler warning. Make sure that you use the `${}` syntax when accessing defines!

NSIS has a concept called the shell context and the $AppData constant is affected by this:

```
SetShellVarContext current ; Current is the default
DetailPrint AppData=$AppData ; C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming
SetShellVarContext all
DetailPrint AppData=$AppData ; C:\ProgramData (This is in the All Users folder on XP)
SetShellVarContext current ; Restore it back to the default
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah, seems, 
you are using common shell context
Try to set

```
SetShellVarContext current
```

before you are getting $APPDATA.

```
 Var ROAMING_FOLDER_ROOT 
 MessageBox MB_OK 'AppDATA FOLDER "${ROAMING_FOLDER_ROOT}"'  #here i am getting the correct path of the Appdata roaming folder frm variable
Section -Additional
SetShellVarContext current
StrCpy $ROAMING_FOLDER_ROOT "$APPDATA\APPDUMMY\APPFILES"
SetOutPath "$ROAMING_FOLDER_ROOT"
SetOverwrite off 
File "C:\MYAPPSOURCECODE\Models\BookStore.sqlite"
SetOverwrite ifnewer
File "C:\MYAPPSOURCECODE\BIN\AppSettings.xml"
File "C:\MYAPPSOURCECODE\BIN\Resources\defData.xml"
File "C:\MYAPPSOURCECODE\BIN\Resources\dummy.html"
SetOutPath "$ROAMING_FOLDER_ROOT\Resources"
File "C:\MYAPPSOURCECODE\BIN\Resources\appjsfile.js"
SectionEnd
```